# Distance between two Java OpenCV matrices

Tags: java, opencv

I have two *Java* OpenCV [Matrices (Mat)](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat) (which are the [DFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) of two images).

What is the best way to compute the "distance" between these two matrices? (assuming two visually similar DFT's will have a small distance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably not a single best answer for this, because it depends on how you want to measure similarity of images.  However, we can try a couple ideas and see what works best for your situation:

One simple idea is to compute squared error of each cell in the matrices (assuming matrices have same dimensions ROWS,COLS). So, the distance metric for matrices M1 and M2 would be:

```
MAT diff_matrix = M1 - M2;
double distance = diff_matrix.norm();
```

If the matrices have different dimensions, just add new rows/columns to the matrix with fewer rows/columns and fill those extra entries with 0s.

The above idea works pretty well under circumstances where you want to detect that one matrix shares pretty much the same colors in the same areas as the others.  However, depending on your DFT definition and how colors get measured, replacing one color by another might result in otherwise similar images being measured as quite different.  So, another idea is to first normalize the color scheme of your images by making the most kth most prevalent color in the image correspond to the kth color in a pre-defined color scheme.

Another idea would be to compute the eigenvectors for the matrices first, and then compute the difference of the eigenvectors then square the differences.  If the matrices are not square, you will need to compute the Singular-Value-Decomposition (SVD) for these matrices to perform these operations.  The advantage of comparing the eigenvectors is that the eigenvectors will be the same as long as the ordering of the rows or columns of your matrices are the same.

Finally, you might consider a mix of these ideas and combine their results in a linear combination.